# PHP Error: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, undefined

It seems like this might be an error dealing with arrays, but I can't figure it out. I'm really just starting with PHP and this is getting to be a little intimidating.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! here is my code:

```
<?php echo "<h1>Choose a Poll!</h1>";

$read = file('poll_topics.txt');   
$data = array( );           
foreach($read as $lines){           
    list($key,$v) = explode("|","$lines");          
    $data[$key] = $v;
}

foreach ($data as $k=>$desc){               
    echo "<ul><li><a href='take_a_poll.php?poll=$k'>$k</a> - $desc </li></ul>";
}

?>
```

Here is what is in the text file:

```
  Instruments|What kind of instruments do you like?
  Music|What type of music do you like best?
```

I should clarify:
The error is line 20, or where it says `list($key,$v) = explode...`

Comment: Why is $lines like "$lines" ?? with quotes I mean. Have you tried without them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an empty line somewhere. That's why `explode()` will return only an empty $key, but have nothing to assign to the $v. And that's when it prints that notice.

You can rewrite it a bit to ignore such cases:

```
foreach ($read as $lines) {
    $key = strtok($lines, "|");
    $v = strtok("|");
    if ($v) {
        $data[$key] = $v;
    }
}
```

This will also avoid an empty entry in your final $data array.

Comment: I have to use the explode() function unfortunately, but thanks for the alternative!

Comment: That's unfortunate. Even fgetcsv would be a nicer function here. But if you want a lazy alternative: `@list($key, $v) = explode()` would suppress the notice. You will have to do the `if ($v)` check in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the tiip, but it's not working yet. I put in 0 parameters and it gave me 3 horrible errors. whatever it is, the errors keep focusing on "list($key,$v) = explode("|","$lines");"

Comment: You forget to prefix the `@` then. But anyway, which errors? And why do you *"have"* to use explode?

Comment: It's technically for a longterm project, and one of the requirements is to use the explode() function.

Comment: When I use the @, it all goes blank. if i leave the () blank without the @, i get "wrong number of parameters for explode()

Comment: Hmm, yes. That was an example. The complete line should read `@list($key,$v) = explode("|","$lines");` like in your original code, just with the prefix.

Comment: the error went away! Thank you so much! I have no idea how that worked, but it did!

Comment: But don't forget the `if ($v) {` block! Else you might end up with an empty entry in the final $data list.

Comment: I did not forget! thanks again! currently trying to fix a similar error on the next page.

Comment: @mario Just out of curiosity, why would your spec insist upon using a specific function? Sounds weird.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php 

echo "<h1>Choose a Poll!</h1>";
$_fileData = file_get_contents('poll_topics.txt'); 
$_results = array();

if ( ! empty( $_fileData ) )
{
    foreach ( $_fileData as $_line ) 
    {
        $_split = explode( '|', $_line );

        //  Many ways to do this:
        //  if ( !empty( $_split ) && 2 == count( $_split ) ) then no error else error
        //  or...
        if ( isset( $_split[0], $_split[1]  ) )
        {
            $_key = $_split[0];
            $_value = $_split[1];

            if ( null !== $_key && null !== $_value )
            {
                $_results[ $_key ] = $_value;
                    //  or  $_results[] = array( $_key => $_value ); if key can be duplicated
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Check the return value from file_get_contents. Most likely it's not able to read the file. So give it an absolute path or make sure the file isn't empty and in the same directory as your php script. Also, check the return value of $_fileData. I will revise code to show you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `array_pad()` function.
Use it where you wrote the explode function.

```
$_split = array_pad(explode( '|', $_line ), numberOfElementsInArray, null);
```