# Undefined offset: 1 php

Tags: php

```
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //Split the HEADERS and BODY 
    list($h, $EALOGIN) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
    $r = explode("\r\n", $h);

    //EASW Key
    $s = explode(":", $r[7]);
    $t = explode(";", $s[1]);
    $EASW_KEY = $t[0]; 
    //Session Key
    $m = explode(":", $r[8]);
    $n = explode(";", $m[1]);
    $EASF_SESS = $n[0];
    //nuc
    $a = explode("<nucleusId>", $EALOGIN);
    $b = explode("</nucleusId>", $a[1]);
    $NUC = $b[0];
```

The offline refers to the "$a" line.
I don't understand the error.
How can i solve it?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400332/php-error-undefined-offset-1

Comment: That is probably not an error. Look closer, it is a warning! $a contains only one single element with index `0`. So `$a[1]` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be due to `$a[1]` not being set.

The delimiter was probably not found in this statement:

```
$a = explode("<nucleusId>", $EALOGIN);
```

Try using debug statements (var_dump()'s, etc) and experimenting with the code to find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined offset" means, that some array has no element with specyfic key. It probably `$a` array.

I suggest to debug that code like this:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//Split the HEADERS and BODY 
list($h, $EALOGIN) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
$r = explode("\r\n", $h);

//EASW Key
$s = explode(":", $r[7]);
$t = explode(";", $s[1]);
$EASW_KEY = $t[0]; 
//Session Key
$m = explode(":", $r[8]);
$n = explode(";", $m[1]);
$EASF_SESS = $n[0];
//nuc
$a = explode("<nucleusId>", $EALOGIN);

// debug start
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
// debug end

$b = explode("</nucleusId>", $a[1]);
$NUC = $b[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with preg_match

```
$pattern = "/<nucleusId>(.*)<\/nucleusId>/";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$NUC = $matches[1];
```